# 'Expected class, delegate, enum, interface,or struct' in XNA 4.0?

Tags: xna-4.0

Here's my code;

I've looked it up online, but still unable to fix it.

Please show me a fixed version of the code, thank you so much! I've been staring at the screen for half 'n' hour and still can't figure this out!

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{

    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D car1Texture;
    Vector2 car1Position = new Vector2(200f, 100f);    
    Texture2D background;        
    Rectangle mainFrame;



    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        //Change the resolution to 800x600            
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1000;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 800;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        // Load the background content.
        background = Content.Load<Texture2D>("roadscan");
        // Set the rectangle parameters
        mainFrame = new Rectangle(0, 0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        car1Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("car1");
    }

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
}

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        KeyboardState keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
        GamePadState gamePad = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);

        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || gamePad.DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            ballPosition.X -= 3f;
        }

        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || gamePad.DPad.Right == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            ballPosition.X += 3f;
        }

        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || gamePad.DPad.Right == ButtonState.Pressed)
        { 
        ballPosition.Y += 3f;
        }

        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || gamePad.DPad.Right == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
        ballPosition.Y -= 3f;
        }

        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        // Draw the background.


        // Start building the sprite.
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        // Draw the background.
        spriteBatch.Draw(background, mainFrame, Color.White);
        // End building the sprite.
        spriteBatch.End();


        // TODO: Add your drawing code here

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: protected override void UnloadContent() Line 76 ('void' is underlined in red) //// protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) Line 86 ('void' underlined in red), ///// protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) Line 127 (void underlined in red)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra brace above the `UnloadContent` method

Right here:

```
     // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
}<-------Delete this guy!!!

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got one to many closing curly braces.

```
  protected override void LoadContent()
  {
    // snip
  }  //close method

    // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
}  //close class
```

You accidentally close the class half way through, just removing the curly brace will fix things. This is common when you haven't shrunk or removed the default comment blocks as they tend to get in the way after you've learnt what all the basic methods do.